# Drop hive partition by date range

Tags: hive

I use hive-0.10.0-cdh-4.7.0 in my environment.

I have a table named test store as sequence file and some partitions by date_dim like below:

```
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-01    
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-11    
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-21    
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-31
```

I want to drop partitions between 2014-07-21 and 2014-07-30 in SQL command:

```
alter table test drop partition (date_dim>='2014-07-11',date_dim<='2014-07-30')
```

I hope these 2 partitions be deleted:

```
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-11    
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-21
```

But actually, these 3 partitions be deleted:

```
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-01
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-11
game=Test/date_dim=2014-07-21
```

It seems hive drop partition only use the `date_dim<='2014-07-30'` condition.

Is there anyway to make hive drop partition as I wish?

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the string to the date type, for that purpose you can use unix_timestamp function:

```
alter table test drop partition (unix_timestamp(date_dim,'yyyy-MM-dd')>=unix_timestamp('2014-07-11','yyyy-MM-dd'),unix_timestamp(date_dim,'yyyy-MM-dd')<=unix_timestamp('2014-07-30','yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Comment: I am getting error. Any idea how to resolve the error? alter table isso_evt_vw_prev drop partition (unix_timestamp(loaddate,'yyyyMMdd')>=unix_timestamp('20160219','yyyyMMdd'));
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:59 mismatched input '(' expecting set null in drop partition statement (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: Be sure that loaddate field has appriate type. String, timestamp vs.